# How to compute $\sum\limits_{a=1}^{\infty}\int_0^b\lambda\left(\int_0^{\lambda}e^{-t}t^{a-1}dt\right)d\lambda$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Please suggest an efficient method to compute the following integral
\begin{equation}
I = \sum\limits_{a=1}^{\infty}\int_0^b\lambda\left(\int_0^{\lambda}e^{-t}t^{a-1}dt\right)d\lambda
\end{equation}
One can see that the quantity in the parenthesis is incomplete gamma function. So, one of the methods is to write this gamma function as an infinite series and perform the integration term by term. But since it will create one infinite series inside another, it will be computationally expensive to follow this method.

Can anyone suggest any other faster way?
What would happen if the integral is modified as follows?
\begin{equation}
I = \sum\limits_{a=1}^{\infty}\int_0^b\lambda\left(\int_0^{\lambda}e^{-t}t^{a-1}dt\right) \left(\int_0^{\alpha\lambda}e^{-t_1}t_1^{a-1}dt_1\right) d\lambda
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the order of integration. The set you are integrating is

$$\{(t,\lambda): \lambda\in [0,b], t\in [0,\lambda]\}$$

This set can also be expressed as

$$ \{ (t,\lambda):t\in [0,b],\ \lambda\in [t,b] \} $$

Therefore you get

$$I = \sum_{a=1}^\infty \int_0^b\left(\int_t^b\lambda e^{-t}t^{a-1}d\lambda \right)dt = \sum_{a=1}^\infty \int_0^be^{-t}t^{a-1} \left(\int_t^b\lambda d\lambda \right)dt$$

$$ = \sum_{a=1}^\infty \int_0^be^{-t}t^{a-1} \frac{b^2-t^2}{2}dt $$

The rest of the calculation is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thank you. I have just one more query now. What would happen if the integral is modified like
\begin{equation}
I = \sum\limits_{a=1}^{\infty}\int_0^b\lambda\left(\int_0^{\lambda}e^{-t}t^{a-1}dt\right)\left(\int_0^{\alpha\lambda}e^{-t_1}t_1^{a-1}dt_1\right)d\lambda
\end{equation}
I am not sure whether it is right to ask another question in the comment section.

Comment: Thank you. I have just one more query to ask. What would happen if the integral is modified as follows
\left(\int_0^{\lambda}e^{-t}t^{a-1}dt\right)

Comment: If your question is how to deal with a third function of the "incomplete gamma shape" $e^{-t_1}t_1^{a-1}$, I honestly don't know how to deal with that.